# How to move past the linking information when using gdb's `starti`?

Tags: c++, gdb

Some debuggers (like pdb) automatically break at your first line of code, then allow you to add breakpoints as needed. I'd really like to have that functionality with gdb. (I need to trace code execution through a huge codebase, and none of my guesses as to where to set a breakpoint have been correct, so the program just runs through to the end.) I've read that you can get similar functionality with gdb's `starti` command, but gdb takes it a little too literally: it stops on the VERY first line of the program where the linking information is. How can I move past this and actually step into my program? I've tried running the `s` command, but nothing looks familiar.

Here's a picture of what I see when I run `starti`.

[image: image of stack trace with linking information]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `start`, not `starti`. `start` puts a temporary breakpoint on your `main()` function and begins executing. It should start at the beginning of your program proper.